# Text wrap in table with fill-remaining-width middle column

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to get a horizontal line to stretch between the first and last columns in a table but I need the first and last columns to wrap if the text is long. The only way I have found to get the desired effect is to use `width:100%;` on the middle column, and `white-space:nowrap;` on the first and last, but I need to find another way as I need the text to wrap when there isn't enough space. Is there a way to achieve this effect in plain CSS?

https://jsfiddle.net/macu/8axk5qv5/4/

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 100%;
}

.line {
  border-top: thin solid blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Title cell with a long title that should wrap</td>
    <td><div class="line"></div></td>
    <td>Another cell, should wrap</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If the text is long enough there should be no line, and the text should wrap normally:
[image: showing wrapping text]

Comment: can you show a screenshot of the output you want ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Added in edit. No line if text is long, and text should wrap.

Comment: and it should be table ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a span or div in each cell, and make them to use white background, then set the line on the table row to create such layout visually.

Check out the fiddle demos below, so you can easily resize and see the wrapping text.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4dfyp2hu/)**

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table tr {
  background: linear-gradient(blue, blue) center/99.99% 1px no-repeat;
}

.table div {
  background: white;
  display: inline-block;
}

.middle div {
  min-width: 100px; /*remove or adjust value as need*/
}

.last {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td class="first">
      <div>Title cell with a long title that should wrap</div>
    </td>
    <td class="middle">
      <div><!-- This td can be removed if no min-width needed --></div>
    </td>
    <td class="last">
      <div>Another cell, should wrap</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But using flexbox can make it much easier, if you don't have to use table.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dLerr4wc/)**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.line {
  background: linear-gradient(blue, blue) center/1px 1px repeat-x;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 100px; /*remove or adjust value as need*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Title cell with a long title that should wrap</div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div>Another cell, should wrap</div>
</div>
```

Comment: good solution for the first one but you still have a small pixel of blue when they collapse

Comment: hmm, using width 99.99% for the background size seems to be ok.

Comment: @Stickers Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

try by removing the  white-space: nowrap; on the TD tag, then target the first and the third TD with

```
td {
vertical-align: middle;
//white-space: nowrap;
}
td:nth-child(1),td:nth-child(3) {
//add whatever min-width AND max-width so it could be something like this
min-width:150px;
max-width:300px;
}
```

see if that helps.